# R colour code plot by rownames for principal component analysis

Tags: r

I am attempting to complete a principal component analysis on a set of data containing columns of numeric data.

Assuming a dataset like this (in reality I have a pre configured data frame, this one if for reproducibility):

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
v2 <- c(3,6,2,5,2,4,9)
v3 <- c(6,1,4,2,3,7,5)
dataset <-data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
row.names(dataset) <-c('New York', 'Seattle', 'Washington DC', 'Dallas', 'Chicago','Los Angeles','Minneapolis')
```

I have ran my principal component analysis, and successfully plotted it:

```
pca=prcomp(dataset,scale=TRUE)

plot(pca$x[,1], pca$x[,2],
     xlab="First PC",ylab="Second PC")
text(pca$x[,1], pca$x[,2],cex=0.7,pos=3,col="darkgrey")
```

What I want to do however is colour code my data points based on the city, which is the row names of my dataset. I also want to use these cities (i.e. rownames) as labels.

I've tried the following, but neither have worked:

```
## attempt 1 - I get row labels, but no chart
plot(pca$x[,1], pca$x[,2],col=rownames(dataset),pch=rownames(dataset),
     xlab="First PC",ylab="Second PC")
text(pca$x[,1], pca$x[,2],labels=rownames(dataset),cex=0.7,pos=3,col="darkgrey")

## attempt 2
datasetwithcity = rownames_to_column(dataset, var = "city")
head(datasetwithcity)

OnlyCities=datasetwithcity[,1]
OnlyCities

# this didn't work:
City_Labels=as.numeric(OnlyCities)
head(City_Labels)

# gets city labels, but loses points and no colour
plot(pca$x[,1], pca$x[,2],col=City_Labels,pch=City_Labels,
     xlab="First PC",ylab="Second PC")
text(pca$x[,1], pca$x[,2],labels=rownames(dataset),
     cex=0.7,pos=3,col="darkgrey")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this.

In base R, you could do:

```r
plot(pca$x[,1], pca$x[,2],
     xlab="First PC",ylab="Second PC", col = seq(nrow(pca$x)),
     xlim = c(-2.5, 2.5), ylim = c(-2, 2))
text(pca$x[,1], pca$x[,2],cex=0.7,pos=3,col="darkgrey")
text(x = pca$x[,1], y = pca$x[,2], labels = rownames(pca$x), pos = 1)
```

[image]

Personally, I think the resulting aesthetics are nicer (and more easy to change to suit your needs) with `ggplot`. The code is also a bit easier to read once you get used to the syntax.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- as.data.frame(pca$x)
df$city <- rownames(df)

ggplot(df, aes(PC1, PC2, color = city)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = city) , vjust = 2) +
  lims(x = c(-2.5, 2.5), y = c(-2, 2)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>